# How to understand sinus?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> In $\Delta PQR$ we have $\angle PQR=60^\circ$, $QR=4$ and $PR=a$.
>   For which values of $a$ are there 0, 1 and 2 triangles matching the description?

I think I'm supposed to use the law of sines, but I really don't understand the question. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Draw a picture whenever you don't understand a geometry problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion must be divided into 4 separate cases.

(figure 1)

[image]

Case-1  $RP = a = 4 \sin 60^0 = … = 2 \sqrt 3$, the critical value.

RP is just long enough to ‘touch’ the line QP. Obviously, only 1 triangle can be formed.

---

Case 2 (figure 2) $a \lt 2 \sqrt 3$

When RP is less than the critical value, no triangle can be formed.

---

Case 3 (figure 3) $2 \sqrt 3 \lt a \lt 4$

Both $⊿QRP_1$ and $⊿QRP_2$ . qaulify.

---

Case 4 (figure 4) $a \gt 4$

Only $⊿QRP_2$ qaulifies. Why QRP1 is not?

Answer (score 0):

Well, by the law of sines, you have $$\frac{a}{\sin(60^\circ)}=\frac{4}{\sin(x^\circ)}$$
where $x^\circ=\angle QRP$, and we have $0<x<120$ (and $a>0$). To find how many triangles there are, all we need to do is to count the number of solutions for $x$ in this equation.

First we rewrite the equation be evaluating $\sin(60^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and solving for $\sin(x^\circ)$:

$$\sin(x^\circ)=\frac{8a}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Since $\sin$ cannot be bigger than $1$, we have no solutions for $a>\frac{\sqrt 3}{8}$.

If $\sin$ is exactly $1$, there is only one solution in our interval: $x=90^\circ$, so we have one solution for $a=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}$.

If $\sin$ is between $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $1$, we have two solutions (one greater than $90$ and the other less than $90$), so there are two solutions for $a\in(\frac{3}{16},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8})$.

Finally, if $\sin$ is between $0$ and $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, there is just one solution (we lose our greater than $90$ solution because $x$ gets bigger than $120$), so there is one solution for $a\in(0,\frac{3}{16}]$.

The idea is that we can decide a horizontal line and are looking for the number of intersections on part of a circle.

[image]

In the top case there are no solutions, in the middle case there are two solutions and in the bottom case there is just one solution.